# How to display text on a recorded video using glsurfaceview?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I made CCTV and Record CCTV screen 
based on  https://github.com/unkei/MyWebRTC.

My source is consists of a streamer and a viewer.

For example, `A` is CCTV streamer.
`B` is CCTV Viewer.

If I connect from `B` to `A` 
show `A` Camera preview

this source only show camera preview.
camera preview is GLSurfaceView.

I want show text on GLSurfaceView.

first I try change `XML`

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCamRecTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

this xml is streamer itself shows the text, but not showing viewer.

and second I try use `Bitmap` `Canvas` `Paint`

```
public void GLText(GL10 gl) { 
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    bitmap.eraseColor(0);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setARGB(0xff, 255, 0, 255);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setTextScaleX(0.5f);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawText("testGLText", 16, 112, paint);

    int[] mTextures = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST );
    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR );

    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT );
    gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT );
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();

}
```

and this source [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uevx.jpg)

this source streamer and viewer show text.
but background color green.

so, I think If `Bitmap` and `Canvas` supplemented, normally show text streamer and viewer.

how to show text on GLSurfaceview on android?
thanks.

Comment: did you try with RelativeLayout.

Comment: sure, `FrameLayout` in  `RelativeLayout`

Comment: No only RelativeLayout

Comment: ah, not use `FrameLayout`? ok, I try this